# How to fix "invalid literal for int() with base 10" in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm setting up a Django web application and want to use call my 'move' object to get the move's artist as defined in the Artist model.

I do not encounter any errors if I remove the variable referencing the ForeignKey in the HTML or if I remove the variable from my Move class in my models.py file.

Here is my models.py file:

```py
from django.db import models

class Move(models.Model):
    move_artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=2)

class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_move = models.ForeignKey(Move, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Here is my html file:

```html
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}


{% block content %}
    <body>
        {% for mov in moves %}
        <p>{{mov.move_artist}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my views.py file:

```
from .models import Move, Artist
from django.shortcuts import render


def cite(request):
    return render(request, 'main/cite.html', {"moves": Move.objects.all()})
```

Here is the error I receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 829, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'Move' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 163, in __get__
        rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 13, in get_cached_value
        return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
    KeyError: 'move_artist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/Documents/Coding/Python/site/site/main/views.py", line 58, in site
    return render(request, 'main/site’, {"moves": Move.objects.all()})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 987, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 837, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 177, in __get__
    rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 144, in get_object
    return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 390, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1281, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 965, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I want the page to display each moves' artist instead of it throwing the error. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the content of this file? `site/site/main/views.py", line 58,`? Also, I think this should be `{"moves": Move.objects.all()}`, notice the open and close parenthesis at the end.

Comment: I added the views.py file and fixed the parenthesis. Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say, this didn't change anything in regards to the end result. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the query inside context, and passing context to the template instead:

```
# views.py 

from .models import Move, Artist
from django.shortcuts import render


def cite(request):
    context = {'moves': Move.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'main/cite.html', context)
```

and then in your template the same markup should have the desired result:

```
{% extends 'main/header.html' %}


{% block content %}

    <body>

      {% for mov in moves %}
        <p>{{mov.move_artist}}</p>
      {% endfor %}

    </body>

{% endblock %}
```

I think the error arises from the fact that you passed a dictionary directly to the template, which is why it came up as TypeError: 'Move' object is not subscriptable. Hopefully this helps.

Try:

```
from django.db import models

class Move(models.Model):
    move_artist = models.ForeignKey('Artist', on_delete=models.CASCADE) # delete default

class Artist(models.Model):
    artist_move = models.ForeignKey(Move, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # delete default
```

Run your migrations and try again. 
*You may have to delete old migrations.

Comment: I updated my views.py to what you suggested, and it unfortunately didn't have an affect on the result.

Code:
def cite(request):
    context = {'moves': Move.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'main/cite.html', context)

Comment: @CodingMom - The problem may be that you are setting defaults for you ForeignKey relation. Try removing the defaults in the models.py, run your migrations, and try again.

Comment: This seemed to fix it. Thanks!